# General pattern of coding a settings UI in an app

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

Look, I know the title is not good. If I've thought of a good one, I might have Googled it and found something by now. So, if you have a better title, please help me edit it. :)

I'm actually not sure if this problem sits better on Programmers SE, but anyways:

### My situation:

I am building a **desktop HTML5 app** with nw.js so **I'm using JS as my programming language** here. As I advance my progress on expanding my app, **I found that my way of hard coding the finding and validating of the values in my settings UI is really a mess** and not really good. I'm self taught and not studying in a university yet so I haven't learned any programming theories so please bear with me. :(

### Demo of my current app settings UI

Please note that the following JS in the code is not completely related to my problem. They are just used to power the UI.

```js
$.fn.extend({
  dropdown: function(cb) {
    this.each(function() {
      var $drop = $(this);
      $drop.find("a").bind("click", function() {
        var selected = $(this).text();
        $drop.find(".selected").text(selected);
        $drop.attr("data-selected", selected.toLowerCase());
        if (typeof cb === "function") {
          cb.call($drop, selected.toLowerCase());
        }
      });
    });
    return this;
  },
  dropdownVal: function(v) {
    var $drop = $(this).first();
    if ($drop.hasClass("dropdown")) {
      if (v !== undefined) {
        v = String(v);
        var c = String(v + " ")[0].toUpperCase() + v.substring(1, v.length);
        $drop.attr("data-selected", v);
        $drop.find(".selected").text(c);
      } else {
        if ($drop.data("selected") !== undefined) {
          return $drop.attr("data-selected");
        } else {
          return $drop.find(".selected").text();
        }
      }
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
});
$(function() {
  $(".dropdown").dropdown(function(s) {
    if (s === "custom") {
      $(this).closest(".form-group").find(".custom").fadeIn();
    } else {
      $(this).closest(".form-group").find(".custom").fadeOut();
    }
  });
  $("#options-ratio-dropdown").dropdown();
  $("#options-dimension-dropdown").dropdown();
  $("#options-max-length-dropdown").dropdown();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h1>This snippet is just to demo my structure and UI, not code!</h1>
<h4> General Settings</h4>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Ratio</label>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="dropdown" id="options-ratio-dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          <span class="selected">Original</span>
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a>Original</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>4:3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>16:9</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>Custom</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 form-horizontal custom" id="options-ratio-custom" style="display:none;">
      <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">Custom:</label>
      <div class="ratio-input col-xs-8">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <input type="text" class="form-control number-input ratio-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 colon">
          <span>:</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <input type="text" class="form-control number-input ratio-2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Width of Dimension</label>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="dropdown" id="options-dimension-dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          <span class="selected">Original</span>
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a>Original</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>800</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>Custom</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 form-horizontal custom" style="display:none;">
      <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">Custom:</label>
      <div class="input-group col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control number-input" id="options-dimension-custom-input">
        <span class="input-group-addon">px</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>GM Writing Thread Limit</label>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control number-input" id="options-gm-writing-thread-limit-input" value="5" placeholder="Default: 5">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="#options-save-btn" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
```

This is how I currently handle on click `#options-save-btn`:

```
$("#options-save-btn").click(function(){
    var fail = false,
        tsettings = {}; //temp settings object
    if ($("#options-ratio-dropdown").dropdownVal() === "custom") { //dropdownVal is my own extended method and it does work
        if (isNaN($("#options-ratio-custom .ratio-1").val()) || isNaN($("#options-ratio-custom .ratio-2").val()) || $("#options-ratio-custom .ratio-1").val() == 0 || $("#options-ratio-custom .ratio-2").val() == 0) {
            fail = true;
            alert("<b>Error: Both numbers in a ratio cannot be non-integer or 0</b>");
        } else {
            tsettings["ratio"] = $("#options-ratio-custom .ratio-1").val() + ":" + $("#options-ratio-custom .ratio-2").val();
        }
    } else {
         tsettings["ratio"] = $("#options-ratio-dropdown").dropdownVal();
    }
    //Repeating if...else for every settings manually
    //Some awkward hard code for the few checkboxes
    tsettings["specialMode"]["isMode"] = $("#options-special-mode").is(":checked");
    if(!fail) {
        for(key in tsettings) {
            settings[key] = tsettings[key];//Transfer temp settings to real settings object
        }
        if (saveSettings()) {//My own function for saving settings locally into a json
            changeLayout();//done
        }
    }
})
```

### The problem

As you can see, every validation of every setting is hard coded by hand and **I felt this is not the right way of doing "settings" for any app**.

### My thoughts

I know there must be a better way, a more automated way for the program to iterate the settings UI and just grab the values and run the preset validation function like `checkFileNameLegal`, `isPercentage`, `checkPathLegal`, etc. and put them like `<div class="form-group" data-input-type="dropdown" data-validation-method="isPercentage">` as a wrapper of the setting input. So that is my thought of how I'll improve my app. **But how do others do settings? Like how does Windows do it in its Control Panel?!**

I have tried Googling but it seems my keywords aren't right. **What is the general practice of making a settings UI, or making the saving part in JS more automated and easier to add new setting items?**

I have read my question a few times now and I think it is rather hard to explain :(, so if you have any trouble understanding my question, please kindly comment down below and I'll provide further info.

Comment: No one? Really? Ok, maybe it's just me...